# How to map data from a C struct containing a string to a Swift struct

Tags: c, swift

I have the following C type:

```
typedef struct {
  uint8_t f1;  
  uint8_t f2;
  bool f3;
  float f4;   
  float f5;  
  char f6[14 + 1];  
} configuration_type;
```

I mapped it to the following Swift struct:

```
public struct Configuration: Encodable {
    public var f1: UInt8
    public var f2: UInt8
    public var f3: Bool
    public var f4: Float
    public var f5: Float 
    var d1: UInt8
    var d2: UInt8
    var d3: UInt8
    var d4: UInt8
    var d5: UInt8
    var d6: UInt8
    var d7: UInt8
    var d8: UInt8
    var d9: UInt8
    var d10: UInt8
    var d11: UInt8
    var d12: UInt8
    var d13: UInt8
    var d14: UInt8
    var d15: UInt8

 public var f6: String {
        get {
            var ret = [UInt8]()
            ret.append(d1)
            ....
            ret.append(d15)
            let s = String(cString: ret)
            return s
        }

        set(newF6) {
            let buf: [UInt8] = Array(newF6.utf8)
            if buf.count > 0 {
                d1 = buf[0]
            }
            else {
                d1 = 0
            }
            if buf.count > 1 {
                d2 = buf[1]
            }
            else {
                d2 = 0
            }
            .....
        }
   }
}
```

When I fill it with the received data using:

```
configuration = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Configuration.self) }
```

everything works but my solution looks like definitely clumsy.

How can I map the c-string into the swift string in a more manageable way?

Comment: Doesn't Swift have arrays? It does.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it does. Do you mean that I have to define an array of UInt8 anyway? How do I define a constant length array in Swift?

Comment: IDK that. I was surprised to see you itemise each array element individually.

Comment: @WeatherVane Swift arrays are dynamic arrays.  The array in the C struct is a fixed array, which Swift imports as a tuple consisting of 15 `UInt8` members.  So if you want the Swift struct to match the memory layout of the C struct, `f6` can't be a stored Swift `Array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the C type directly (make sure it's defined in a header that your bridging header includes).

Swift will import the C struct as

```swift
struct configuration_type
{
    public var f1: UInt8
    public var f2: UInt8
    public var f3: UInt8 // I'm pretty sure it doesn't match to Bool
    public var f4: Float
    public var f5: Float

    public var f6: (Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8, Int8)
}
```

Then you can extend it

```swift
typealias Configuration = configuration_type

extension Configuration
{
    public var f3Bool: Bool
    {
        get { f3 != 0 }
        set
        {
            f3 = newValue ? 1 : 0
           /*
              Last I checked, the compiler eliminates the implicit 
              branch in the ternary expression, emitting code that
              is nearly as efficient as the direct cast.  But you
              you could do a direct cast yourself

              f3 = unsafeBitCast(newValue, UInt8.self) }
             */
        }
    }

    public var f6AsString: String
    {
        get
        {
            withUnsafeBytes(of: f6) {
                String(cString: $0.bindMemory(to: CChar.self).baseAddress!)
            }
        }
        set
        {
            newValue.withCString
            { src in
                withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &f6)
                {
                    let dst = $0.bindMemory(to: CChar.self)
                    strncpy(dst.baseAddress!, src, dst.count)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend using the C struct directly because it helps avoid duplicating code.  If for some reason the struct has to be altered in C, members moved or new ones added, then your Swift code will automatically be in sync.

Comment: Thank you Chip, it looks like promising, unfortunately I get a compilation error 'No exact matches in call to initializer' on this line: String(cString: $0.bindMemory(to: CChar.self)). Any suggest?

Comment: @Fab, sorry that was a boneheaded mistake on my part.  `String(cString:)` expects an `UnsafePointer<CChar>`, but `$0.bindMemory(to: CChar.self)` results in an `UnsafeBufferPointer<CChar>`.  You have to use its `baseAddress` similar to what is done in the setter.   I updated my answer to fix it.  I also removed the cast to `CInt` in the call to `strncpy`.   `strncpy` takes a `size_t` not an `int` in C, and Swift matches `size_t` to `Int` rather than `CInt`.

Comment: When I write code that has to deal with C strings, I often have an extension on `String` that includes an `init(cString:UnsafeBufferPointer<CChar>)`.  It's convenient, but it's easy to forget that it's a *custom* initializer that isn't necessarily in someone else's code.